# Defining equivalence between parent and child classes

Tags: python, python-3.x

What is the best practice for defining an equality operation to determine if a parent and child are effectively the same? Is there any good way to achieve this, or should I just avoid this desired behavior with a architecture change?

#### Parent Class

```
class Equal1(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value=value
    def get_value(self):
        return self.value
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, self.__class__):
            return self.__dict__==other.__dict__
        return NotImplemented
```

#### Child Class

```
class Equal2(Equal1):
    def __init__(self, value):
        super().__init__(2 * value)
        self.other_values = ''
```

I want the following code to evaluate to `True`:

```
a = Equal1(2)
b = Equal2(1)
a == b
## True
```

It currently will not evaluate to `True` because the dictionaries are not identical, even if the functionality is the same.

One potential technique is to iterate through the smaller dictionary to check all of the key/value pairs to make sure they are the same as well as checking the local attributes using `dir()`.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to ignore the keys that only one of the objects has?

I would suggest replacing:

```
return self.__dict__==other.__dict__
```

with:

```
return all(self[k] == other[k] 
           for k in self.__dict__.keys() & other.__dict__.keys())
```

This makes the objects equal if all the keys, they both have, have equal values.